# vmware tools does not work in ubuntu 12.04 guest

Tags: 12.04, vmware, guest-os

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 on vmware workstation 8.0.4. I am trying to install vmware tools, but I got stuck on this step:

The filesystem driver (vmhgfs module) is used only for the shared folder 
feature. The rest of the software provided by VMware Tools is designed to work 
independently of this feature.

If you wish to have the shared folders feature, you can install the driver by 
running vmware-config-tools.pl again after making sure that gcc, binutils, make
and the kernel sources for your running kernel are installed on your machine. 
These packages are available on your distribution's installation CD.
[ Press Enter key to continue ]

I have installed gcc, binutils, build-essential, make, and linux-headers-$(uname -r) are installed (per this thread: [How to make sure that gcc, binutils, make and the kernel source are installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74412/how-to-make-sure-that-gcc-binutils-make-and-the-kernel-source-are-installed))

It still asks me for those things on the next run of sudo vmware-config-tools.pl

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is probably already answered over here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/159903/is-vmware-8-compatible-with-ubuntu-12-04